# Run a separate function for each item depending on the value of another variable with dplyr

Tags: r, switch-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset which contains a categorical variable. Depending on the value of this variable, I want to run a different function for each such value. All the possible functions have the same return type. I might wish to run say, sin() if category is 'A', cos() if category is 'B', and tan() if category is 'C'.

The real application for this is in simulating populations, where outcomes depend on the values of categories, but sometimes in very different ways.

**Toy example**

```
library(dplyr)
category=c('A','B','C')
N <- 100
pop <- as.data.frame(ID <- seq(1:N))
pop <- as.tbl(pop)
pop$Category <- sample(category,N,replace=TRUE)
pop$score <- runif(N)
pop
tf <- function(x,EXPR) {
switch(EXPR,
A = cos(x),
B = sin(x),
C = tan(x)
)}
pop$results <- tf(pop$Score,pop$Category)
```

This code fails,reasonably enough, with the error message

```
Error in switch(EXPR, A = cos(x), B = sin(x), C = tan(x)) : EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

I have looked, carefully, at dplyr and do, and I can easily see how to run the same function for each category separately. However, I need a function which depends on the category value.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code in your toy example fails at line 4. Please edit the code to make the example reproducible.

Comment: I second that motion. What is `pop`?

Comment: Sorry, well spotted - pop is just a dataframe, and it must have existed in my environment when I ran the test.

Comment: Three very helpful answers and some pertinent comments too. I will explore these. As the context is simulating moderately large populations, I feel some benchmarking coming on. When I get it done, I will add an answer below.  Many thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 2):

The `rowwise` function is what you need to force it evaluate row by row...

```
    pop<-data.frame(ID=1:100, 
                    category = sample(c("A", "B", "C"),100,replace=TRUE), 
                    score = runif(100)) 

    exprs<-function(category, score){   
        if(category=="A")
          ret <-  sin(score)   
        if(category=="B")
          ret <-  cos(score)   
        if(category=="C")
          ret <-  tan(score)   
        ret }



    pop %>%    
        rowwise %>%    
        mutate(answer = exprs(category, score))
```

Source: local data frame [100 x 4]
Groups:

```
# A tibble: 100 × 4
      ID category     score    answer
   <int>   <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1        C 0.5219332 0.5751317
2      2        C 0.9266336 1.3314972
3      3        B 0.2729260 0.9629863
4      4        B 0.6575110 0.7915158
5      5        B 0.0910481 0.9958580
6      6        C 0.9968752 1.5467554
7      7        A 0.3429183 0.3362369
8      8        A 0.9101669 0.7896062
9      9        B 0.9291849 0.5984872
10    10        C 0.8913347 1.2379742
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Ah, so that is what rowwise does - good advice, and a great chance to learn more. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Vectorize()`:

```
set.seed(42)
category=c('A','B','C')
N <- 10
pop <- data.frame(ID=seq(1:N), Category=sample(category,N,replace=TRUE), score=runif(N), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tf <- function(x, EXPR) switch(EXPR,
         'A' = cos(x),
         'B' = sin(x),
         'C' = tan(x))

TF <- Vectorize(tf)

pop$result <- TF(pop$score, pop$Category)
```

or (thx to @42 for the comment)

```
pop$result <- mapply(tf, pop$score, pop$Category)
```

Comment: Looks very interesting, I had not seen that function before. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. `Vectorize` is a light wrapper around `mapply`.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because you are sending the complete vector , instead of record wise. I used lapply to call your function for each row and it works

```
library(dplyr)
category=c('A','B','C')
N <- 100
pop <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:N))
pop$Category <- sample(category,N,replace=TRUE)
pop$Category <- as.factor(pop$Category)
pop$score <- runif(N)
tf <- function(x,EXPR) {
  switch(EXPR,
         A = cos(x),
         B = sin(x),
         C = tan(x)
  )}

## call tf for every row in the dataframe
pop$results  <-lapply( seq_len(nrow(pop)) , function (i) {     
  tf(pop$score[i],pop$Category[i])
}) %>% unlist
```

Thanks

Comment: I always struggle to remember the lapply, sapply, etc.. functions. Good advice, and thank you very much.

Comment: That's an interesting method of going rowwise through 2 columns, But I wonder if it might be more compact and efficient to use `mapply`

Comment: @astaines and anyone interested in efficiency... this is not likely to be your best method.